# How can I create a base MasterPage class in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm trying to create a base class for a MasterPage in ASP.NET, so that the inheritance structure is as follows:

`System.Web.UI.MasterPage` -> `BaseMasterPage` -> `SiteMasterPage`

`BaseMasterPage` will simply provide some methods and properties that would be the same across several master pages on the site, so I think having a base class here makes sense.

Sources [here](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/07/04/base-classes-and-extending-the-page-directive.aspx) and [here](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/56_Using_Custom_BasePage_Class_in_ASPNet.aspx) suggest that what I'm trying to do is possible with subclasses of the `Page` class, but I can't seem to get it working and I'm wondering if there's something about `MasterPage` that prevents me from doing this.

**Here's what I've got:**

Base.Master.vb (In `App_Code` folder)

```
Public Class BaseMasterPage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

End Class
```

---

Site.Master.vb (in a folder called `Master`)

```
Public Class SiteMasterPage
    Inherits GSHolidays.BaseMasterPage

End Class
```

---

First line of Site.master (also in `Master`)

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.vb" CodeFileBaseClass="GSHolidays.BaseMasterPage" Inherits="GSHolidays.SiteMasterPage" %>
```

---

I've modified the class names, as well as removed the content from the classes for simplicity. The `GSHolidays` namespace is the default defined in the project file.

**Here's the error I'm getting:**

In the browser (when navigating to a page that uses SiteMasterPage):
[image: ASP.NET Error: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl)]
A bit of Googling on this issue lead me to add the `CodeFileBaseClass` property (I originally did not have it included), which doesn't seem to have solved the issue, but has added another one, inside of visual studio -

In Visual Studio 2017:
[image: Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Error: must be subtype of ???]

I can't seem to find any information online regarding this error, and regardless of what I do it doesn't seem to go away (unless I remove the `CodeFileBaseClass` property.

I'm really not sure where to go from here, so I was hoping one of you guys could help me out. I apologise that this question is quite long, though hopefully the issue is something simple and someone is able to point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!